# Screen is inverted when I rotate it

Tags: display

I installed Ubuntu onto my Chromebook recently and I’ve been having an issue with the screen and how it rotates. I also tried Windows but it works fine there but I want to use Ubuntu.

Anyways, onto the actual problem: when I rotate the screen left, or flip it upside down (it’s a 360° laptop with a touch screen) the display rotates the opposite direction. E.g., if I turn the screen right (physically) the display turns left. Or if I just have it normally, like using it as a laptop, the display is upside down and I can’t see.

I also tried to do commands to flip the screen but it only gives a temporary effect ’til I move it again.

Comment: Sorry, it’s Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Lenovo C340-11 Chromebook

Comment: So, please tell how you achieve the temporary effect? IDEA: Maybe there is a way to make it permanent...

Comment: I use the xrandr command to flip it temporarily but I don’t want it to stay on one rotation permanently. The problem is flipping it left rotates the display right.